# Which seller sold the less carrot? What is the formula of it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Who sold the least carrots?

What is the formula? Minif finds the correct value of 10, but how can I get the seller Tom, who sold the 10 carrots? Match doesn't work as pear has also 10 amount...

```
     A       B        C

 1.  Amount Product  Seller

 2.  5  Apple        Tom

 1. 4   Apple        Ann

 3. 15  Pear         Tom

 4. 10  Pear         Ann

 5. 22  Banana       Tom

 6. 12  Banana       Ann

 7. 10  Carrot       Tom

 8. 11  Carrot       Ann

 9. 2   Pear         Ann

 10. 99 Carrot       Ann
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I think this will help you : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2590-excel-vlookup-lowest-value.html#a1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The world is changing and with the arrival of Dynamic Arrays (DA), there are new approaches to this question.

In Excel without DA formulas, you can do this with a helper column that combines Amount and Product into a lookup key value, then use Minifs to determine the lowest number for carrots and combine that with the word "carrot" to create the lookup term for an Index/Match combo.

```
=INDEX(C2:C11,MATCH(MINIFS(A2:A11,B2:B11,E2)&E2,D2:D11,0))
```

In Excel with Dynamic Array formulas, you can use the Filter function to filter the table, return only values from the Seller column and filter on a combination of Product = Carrot and Amount equals the minimum for carrot. All in one formula, without any helper columns.

```
=FILTER(C2:C11,(B2:B11=E2)*(A2:A11=MINIFS(A2:A11,B2:B11,E2)))
```

[image]

How do you know you have Dynamic Array formulas? These are in the process of being rolled out to Office 365 subscribers. If you have the Filter() function then you have Dynamic Array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the solution I was searching for, this doesn't require a helper column:

{=INDEX(C2:C11,MATCH(MINIFS($A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,"Carrot")&"Carrot",$A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11,0))}

-> TOM

I don't know this kind of technique but it works. You write the formula without {} signs and (in Hungarian excel at least) you press shift+control+Enter to enter the formula correctly.

This formula concatenates the A and the B columns in the memory and the match searches for the concatenated vaule.

Filter() is not available for the plebs yet afaik.